# Rails: Add months or years to submitted date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date

I have an ActiveRecord Model called "Funevent".
Funevent has :dateeventbegins and :dateeventends.
My view allows the client to select the :dateeventbegins by using a date_select within the form:

```
<%= f.date_select :dateeventbegins, :start_year => Time.now.year - 1, :end_year => Time.now.year %>
```

Then in same form I allow the client to specify how long this event lasts rather than directly choosing an end date (I have good reasons for this). So I have:

```
<%= select_tag :goodforX, options_for_select(['Never ending', '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11']) %>
<%= select_tag :goodforY, options_for_select(['Never ending', 'Months','Years']) %>
```

When this data comes back to the Controller I need to be able to **Increment** the :dateeventbegins by what the client specified in the form and set that as my :dateeventends if the client did not specify that this is a "Never ending" event.

So now in my Controller I tried this to see if I could start simple by incrementing the submitted date manually and then move onto the more complicated part of incrementing by what the client specified. I started with:

```
if params[:goodforX] != "Never ending" or params[:goodforY] != "Never ending"
  params[:funevent][:dateeventends] = params[:funevent][:dateeventbegins].todate + 3.months 
end
```

My first problem is that this starter step does not work. I am getting this error:

> undefined method `todate' for nil:NilClass

Perhaps it has something to do with how the date the client specified is not coming into the controller purely as a date. Instead it looks like this is what the controller sees:

```
"funevent"=>{ 
"dateeventbegins(1i)"=>"2014",
"dateeventbegins(2i)"=>"1",
"dateeventbegins(3i)"=>"1" }
```

How do I access these submitted values and increment them by the client specified measures in :goodforX and :goodforY to dynamically create my :dateeventends?

Comment: first of all itz `to_date` not `todate`...but your `params[:funevent]` or `params[:funevent][:dateeventbegins]` is also coming as nil...place a debugger and see what params are you getting

Comment: I show what params I am getting for params[:funevent][:dateeventbegins] - it sees it as dateeventbegins(1i), ..(2i), ..(3i). These are the values for the year, month, day in the select on the form. But they come in separately rather than being together as a date. Rails handles this automatically (the conversion to a date) when it adds it to the database. But, I'm not sure the best way to handle it in my code to add some time and make a new var for the :dateeventends.